# node.js Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first

Tags: node.js, sql-server, web-services

I'm trying to create web services using node.js from an sql server database,in the frontend when i call those 2 webservices simultaneously it throws an error Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first .

Any Solution ?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var sql = require("mssql");

router.get('/Plant/:server/:user/:password/:database', function(req, res, next) {

    user = req.params.user;
    password = req.params.password;
    server = req.params.server;
    database = req.params.database;


    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: user,
        password: password,
        server: server,
        database:database

    };

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {



        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query("SELECT  distinct PlantName FROM MachineryStateTable"
            , function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) console.log(err)
                else {

                    for(i=0;i<recordset.recordsets.length;i++) {
                        res.send(recordset.recordsets[i])
                    }

                }
               sql.close();

            });

    });

});





router.get('/Dep/:server/:user/:password/:database/:plantname', function(req, res, next) {

    user = req.params.user;
    password = req.params.password;
    server = req.params.server;
    database = req.params.database;
    plantname = req.params.plantname;

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: user,
        password: password,
        server: server,
        database:database

    };

    sql.connect(config, function (err) {



        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query("SELECT  distinct DepName FROM MachineryStateTable where PlantName= '"+plantname+"'"
            , function (err, recordset) {

                if (err) console.log(err)
                else {

                    for(i=0;i<recordset.recordsets.length;i++) {
                        res.send(recordset.recordsets[i])

                    }
                    sql.close();
                }

            });
    });
});



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to create a `poolConnection`
try this:

```
new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {

  return pool.request().query("SELECT * FROM MyTable")

  }).then(result => {

    let rows = result.recordset
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.status(200).json(rows);
    sql.close();

  }).catch(err => {

    res.status(500).send({ message: `${err}`})
    sql.close();

  });
```

Comment: Thank you,Worked perfectly for me

Comment: Thx. Nice one. Do we need to close the pool? something like pool.close(). Is it possible to define pooling code once and use in many places?

Comment: Thanks, If I use ----  const db_pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(db_config);  Should I call db_pool.close();  instead of sql.close();

Comment: This is soooo  bad....  Do they not know what a connection pool is?  So you create a new 'ConnectionPool' and connect to it.  Seems like a connection to me, not a p ool.  Then you call 'sql.close()'?  Can you create two connection pools at once?  Do you create one for each request?

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://patriksimek.github.io/node-mssql/#close), close method should be used on the connection, and not on the required module,

So should be used like

```
var connection = new sql.Connection({
user: '...',
password: '...',
server: 'localhost',
database: '...'
});
connection.close().
```

Also couple of suggestions,
    1. putting res.send in a loop isn't a good idea, You could reply back the entire recordsets or do operations over it, store the resultant in a variable and send that back.
    2. Try using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), instead of callbacks, it would make the flow neater

Comment: The user of the application is not connected to any database from the login page, he should specify the ipaddress and the password then choose the database .

Comment: The above connection object can be supplied with the credentials coming in the request.

Comment: Can you specify how with an example?

Answer (score 2):

You must use ConnectionPool.

Next function returns a recordset with my query results.

```js
async function execute2(query) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig).connect().then(pool => {
            return pool.request().query(query)
        }).then(result => {

            resolve(result.recordset);

            sql.close();
        }).catch(err => {

            reject(err)
            sql.close();
        });
    });


}
```

Works fine in my code!

Answer (score 1):

if this problem still bother you, then change the core api. 
go to node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js
at line 1723, add below code before if condition
 globalConnection = null

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here trying to find out how to use SQL Server pool connection with parameters:

```
var executeQuery = function(res,query,parameters){

   new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect().then(pool =>{

    // create request object
    var request = new sql.Request(pool);

   // Add parameters
    parameters.forEach(function(p) {
    request.input(p.name, p.sqltype, p.value);
    });

    // query to the database
    request.query(query,function(err,result){

            res.send(result);
            sql.close();

    });
 })       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't read their documentation, I don't think it was written by someone that actually uses the library :)  Also don't pay any attention to the names of things, a 'ConnectionPool' doesn't seem to actually be a connection pool of any sort.  If you try and create more than one connection from a pool, you will get an error.  This is the code that I eventually got working:

```js
const sql = require('mssql');

let pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config); // some object that lets you connect ONCE
let cnn = await pool.connect(); // create single allowed connection on this 'pool'
let result = await cnn.request().query(query);
console.log('result:', result);
cnn.close(); // close your connection
return result;
```

This code can be run multiple times in parallel and seems to create multiple connections and correctly close them.