# Sleep after http request angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm trying to build an angular 2 application,i got 2 http calls in NgOnInit that cannot run simultaneously , i want to sleep some seconds or execute the first request then the second one.
Here is my code

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {


   this._service.getPlant().subscribe(plants => {
      for (var i=0; i<plants.length; i++)
    for (var name in plants[i]) {
       this.plants.push(plants[i][name]);  
    }
    });


this._service.getDept().subscribe(depts => {
      for (var i=0; i<depts.length; i++)
         console.log(depts[i])  
    for (var name in depts[i]) {  
       this.depts.push(depts[i][name]);
    }
    });



  }
```

Any solution ?

Comment: why " that cannot run simultaneously" ?

Comment: i have a problem in my backend node.j  when connecting to sql server it throws Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.

Comment: The question should then be: "how do I fix my NodeJS code?". You wouldn't ask how to drive a car on only two wheels because you have two flat tires, would you? You would fix the flat tires.

Comment: Asked the [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744946/node-js-global-connection-already-exists-call-sql-close-first) no helpful answer

Comment: That doesn't change anything. And it won't fix the problem of two different users sending concurrent requests to your server anyway.

Comment: Any logic solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run getDept() after receiving response from getPlant().

```
public ngOnInit(): void {

    this._service.getPlant().subscribe(plants => {
        for (var i = 0; i < plants.length; i++)
            for (var name in plants[i]) {
                this.plants.push(plants[i][name]);
            }

        this._service.getDept().subscribe(depts => {
            for (var i = 0; i < depts.length; i++)
                console.log(depts[i])
            for (var name in depts[i]) {
                this.depts.push(depts[i][name]);
            }
        });
    });

}
```