# Nodejs Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first

Tags: node.js, npm, async-await

I am new to NodeJs. Can anyone please help me with this function? I am trying to extract data from a SQL Server database.

Where should the `sql.close` be put? I am trying to use the async /await method?

When I execute the code the first time, it works ok. However, from the next execution, it shows an error:

> NodeJs Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.

Code:

```
exports.ExecSQLAsync= async function (query, paramvalue, callback) {
    try {
        let pool = await mssql.connect(settings.db_config);
        let result1 = await pool.request()
            .input('comp_id', mssql.Int, paramvalue)
            .query(query);
            callback(result1.recordset);
    } catch (err) {
        callback(null,err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45544685/6450941

Comment: thank you @atef.  I was able to do it using the promise method successfully.I would like to use the async-await method instead of promise method.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.ExecSQLAsync= async function (query, paramvalue, callback) {
    try {
        let pool = await mssql.connect(settings.db_config);
        let result1 = await pool.request()
            .input('comp_id', mssql.Int, paramvalue)
            .query(query);
        mssql.close();
        callback(result1.recordset);
    } catch (err) {
        mssql.close();
        callback(null,err);
    }
}
```